# Script is not working. I use dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, spring, dojo

I'm creating a web application using `dojo` toolkit's TabConatiner. 
Clicking `fn_addTab("/page", this)` on the Menu will show the page as a tab. It looks like an `iframe`.

But there is a problem. Tabs imported into 'href' attribute, script in jsp don't work. If the url mapped to the controller is shown in the tab, does not the script inside the jsp have to work as well?

**home.js**

```
function fn_addTab(url, node) {
    require([
        'dijit/registry', 
        'dijit/layout/ContentPane', 
        'dojo/domReady!'
    ], function(registry, ContentPane) {

        const tabContainer = registry.byId("tabContainer");

        ...

        let tab = registry.byId(tabId);
        if(typeof tab === 'undefined') {
            tab = new ContentPane({
                id: tabId, 
                title: sidebarMenuText,
                href: url, 
                closable: true
            });
            tabContainer.addChild(tab);
        } 
        tabContainer.selectChild(tab);
        fn_initActiveMenu(node);
    });
}
```

**page.jsp**

```
<section class="wrapper">
   <!-- page start -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="page-header">page 3</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <button id="btn" type="button" onclick="helloWorld()">Click</button>
                </div>
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    <!-- page end-->
</section>

<script>
function helloWorld() {
    alert('helloWorld?');
}
</script>
```

That button is not working. 
helloWorld() is not defined.

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page")
public String page() {
    return "page/page";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Use `dojox/layout/ContentPane`, not `dijit/layout/ContentPane`.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html